# Android ViewHolder: Update only the view clicked

Tags: android, listview

**GetView**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ConditionChecklist conditionChecklist;
    View view = convertView;

    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
        case 0:
            conditionChecklist = mConditionCheckListArray.get(position);
            view = createDropdownRow(conditionChecklist, convertView, parent);
            break;
        case 1:
            conditionChecklist = mConditionCheckListArray.get(position);
            view = createButtonRow(conditionChecklist, convertView, parent);
            break;
    }

    return view;
}
```

**createButtonRow**

```
public View createButtonRow(ConditionChecklist conditionChecklist, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ButtonHolder buttonHolder;

    if (convertView != null) {
        buttonHolder = (ButtonHolder) convertView.getTag();
    } else {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.condition_button_row, parent, false);
        buttonHolder = new ButtonHolder();
        buttonHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_row_title);
        buttonHolder.yes = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_row_yes);
        buttonHolder.no = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_row_no);
        buttonHolder.subQuestion = (AutoCompleteTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_row_autocomplete);
        convertView.setTag(buttonHolder);
    }

    buttonHolder.title.setText(conditionChecklist.getQuestion());
    setButtonRowListeners(buttonHolder);
    setButtonRowAdapters(buttonHolder);

    return convertView;
}
```

**setButtonRowListeners**

```
private void setButtonRowListeners(final ButtonHolder buttonHolder) {
    buttonHolder.yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttonHolder.yes.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            buttonHolder.yes.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            buttonHolder.no.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.lighterGray));
            buttonHolder.no.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.mediumGray));
            buttonHolder.subQuestion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    buttonHolder.no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttonHolder.no.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            buttonHolder.no.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            buttonHolder.yes.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.lighterGray));
            buttonHolder.yes.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.mediumGray));
            buttonHolder.subQuestion.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
```

When I click any yes or no button it's highlighting buttons off the screen. So when I scroll down the buttons in the rows below are already highlighted. I know this is because the ViewHolder is recycling my views. How would I make sure only the view I click will be highlighted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said yourself: the views get recycled.

So when getting a "new" row with `createButtonRow()` you need to update the states of the views you're changing with clicking the buttons.

Furthermore it looks like you're using the `buttonHolder` to store state. This shouldn't be done at all. You need to store the state somewhere else since every time the views get recycled you loose the state.

Comment: he's right, essentially you should be using a data object to reflect the state of the view in a particular row, then when that row needs to be shown, you can display it in the correct state

Comment: So update the model class `ConditionChecklist` with some `boolean` like `isSelected`. Store that in my db. Then when I inflate rows in createButtonRow() check that value and set my background that way?

Comment: @spike_stack that sounds solid

Comment: Thanks, the only confusion i have now is that the views start out both grey. So neither is highlighted. If I click one, then I set that value, update my db, but the view will not be highlighted immediatly. Correct? How would I highlight that view at that exact moment? Cause i'm already inside my adapter and I cant call `notifydatasetchanged`

Comment: @spike_stack that's possible to do like you're doing now. If you have access to your views just do it directly. Persisting the data is only an additional step to take.

Comment: Oh right, I get it, cause when I scroll down to inflate my next row its going to check for that value and it wont be highlighted because the value will be false. Sorry its been a long day. Thanks

Comment: @spike_stack no worries, happy to help